# Reduce bool expression in Scheme

Tags: scheme, racket, boolean-expression

As part of my practice with Scheme I'm designing an arithmetic expression eval. Suppose I am given a list representing an arbitrary boolean expression, and another association list containing a list of **pairs** representing the values of the boolean literals. What I want to do is simplify/reduce the boolean expression so that it goes down to its lower form.

Here is an example:

```
'(a and (b or c)) and '((a . #t) (b . #f) (c . #t)))
```

should reduce to `#t`.

should reduce to just `'a`.

**To make it simpler**, I don't want to handle double-negatives, i.e. `not (not b)`. Also, all unary or  binary boolean expressions are contained around a pair of parentheses `(i.e. a or b or c would be (a or (b or c))`.

I've been fiddling around but I'm quite stuck. Help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry I should have been more explicit, they are both lists. I'm having trouble trying to get through the boolean expression simplifying part.

Answer (score 1):

This solution even works for double negatives. If expression contains letter with missing value, result depends on used operation ("and" returns last truthy argument, "or" returns first truthy).

```
(define (eval-expr expr)
  (cond ((empty? expr) expr)
        ((and (list? expr)
              (= (length expr) 2))
         (not (eval-expr (second expr))))
        ((and (list? expr)
              (= (length expr) 3))
         (if (eq? (second expr) 'and)
             (and 
              (eval-expr (first expr))
              (eval-expr (third expr)))
             (or
              (eval-expr (first expr))
              (eval-expr (third expr)))))
        (#t expr)))

(eval-expr '(a and (#f or #t))) -> #t 
(eval-expr '(not #t))
(eval-expr '(b or #f)) -> b
(eval-expr '(not (#t and #f)))
(eval-expr '(not (not #t)))
```

Comment: Thank you again!! This is almost perfect.. so basically it's not doing what I expect for a few tests..

For example: ```'((#t and (not b)) or ((#t and #f) or ((not b) and #f)))``` should become ```'(not b)``` but it becomes ```#f```, and ```(a and (#f or #t)``` should become ```'a``` but it becomes ```#t``` (because it would be a and #t) => a ... would there be a simple workaround to this? For the test with all variables with a value it seems to work great.

Comment: Results from both examples are expected, because Scheme logical operators see symbols as #t (so (not 'a) -> #f) and "and" returns last true argument. I guess you will have to use macros and create your own logical operators.